# Не работает IF для строки

Tags: c, строки

Почему не останавливается цикл?

```
void main()
{
char line[300];
cout << "Enter words:";
cin >> line;
if (line == "stop" || line == "STOP")
    goto skip;
for(;;)
{
    char s[50];
    cin >> s;
    if (s == "stop")
        break;
    strcat(line, s);
}
skip:
cout << line << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

C-строки сравниваются при помощи функций типа [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp). Непосредственное `==` сравнивает *указатели на строки*.